# Getting Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process, while launching google chrome from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
public void setUp(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/chapter4");
}
```

**Error:**

```
Started ChromeDriver
port=14918
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(89): error: Value of: app_launched
  Actual: 1
Expected: AUTOMATION_SUCCESS
Which is: 0
Error while awaiting automation ping from browser process
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(223): error: Value of: automation()->GetBrowserWindowCount(&window_count)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(244): error: Value of: browser_proxy.get()
  Actual: false
Expected: true
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(269): error: Value of: WaitForBrowserProcessToQuit( TestTimeouts::action_max_timeout_ms(), &exit_code)
  Actual: false
Expected: true
.\test\automation\proxy_launcher.cc(270): error: Value of: exit_code
  Actual: -1
Expected: 0
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. It will launch the browser, then fail to do anything and fail the test.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any help will be Appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it can't find chromedriver.exe to start. In this line:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

the point is to tell it exactly where to locate *chromedriver.exe*, including the full path. You might need to change that to something like:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\My\Path\To\chromedriver.exe");
```

As the [ChromeDriver documentation](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) says:

> Make sure the server can be located on your PATH or specify its location via the `webdriver.chrome.driver` system property.

Comment: but chrome was launched with my code, but it wasn't able to open the homepage.